# Summing a 3D symbolic Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I have a 12x12x12 symbolic matrix, and I want to sum along the second dimension in order to make a 12x12 matrix. Normally, I would just do this with the sum() command as follows:

sum(matrix,2)

However, for symbolic matrices this throws an error that the "Input arguments must be two-dimensional."

Is there a solution or workaround that I should be using?

Comment: Maybe you could sum 1x12x12 sub-matrices? As a comment, generally working with matrices with specific symbolic entries is not the best way to go. There might be a way to rewrite your code to avoid this issue in the first place. Something to consider anyway.

Comment: If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reimplements sum for more dimensions:

```
function M=sumnd(M,dim)
s=size(M);
M=permute(M,[setdiff(1:ndims(M),dim),dim]);
M=reshape(M,[],s(dim));
M=sum(M,2);
s(dim)=1;
M=reshape(M,s);
end
```

I made it consistent to `sum` for doubles, it returns a [12 1 12] array in your case. To get a [12 12] matrix apply squeeze.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I think that M=squeeze(reshape(M,s)); should be included in the last line of the answer though, so as to be consistent with what the standard sum() function does.

Comment: @Meru Bhanot: I don't agree, using a simple example like `size(sum(rand(3,3,3)))` you can clearly see that the built-in sum behaves like the code in my answer.